# Lock your visible score

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I just noticed that my P.SE score is 7337. While not as awesome as [1337](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), it got me to thinking that it would be nice to be able to lock your P.SE score at a certain value. Either discarding upvotes or having a private score that you can set public once you get over the novelty of being "1337". I don't know just a thought.

Comment: It would be nice to have some reputation easter eggs... Something like "reputation not found" when you hit 404 ;)

Comment: Yeah maybe some bronze or silver badges to go with it.

Answer (score 5):

I think I can safely say that this will be marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

If you are really that bothered, then don't ask or answer any more questions. In addition you'll have to mark all of your existing answers community wiki so you'll get no more reputation from them. You can't turn your questions directly into CW posts and I can't see moderators helping out either.

Comment: Not really a big deal, just thought it would be a neat trick :) imagine the irony of a user like Jon Skeet deciding to have a score of 1.

Comment: I find screenshots do a great job of capturing "the perfect rep moment". :)